# get the content of the page formated as it is in nutch

Tags: http, parsing, tomcat, solr, nutch

in  nutch, I'm looking for a way to get the content of the page formated as it is(with lines, new lines, and paragraphs).

the coming code doesn't help because it removes all the format of the page.

```
Parse parse = parseResult.get(content.getUrl());    
parse.getText()
```

even

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new   
ByteArrayInputStream(content.getContent())));
while (br.readLine() != null) 
LOG.info("After br: " +br.readLine());
```

is not the solution since it returns the content formatted but with the html tags.

I really want it to be in its original format, to be able to send it to a method that it will extract the needed content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No direct way to do that.

Study and modify `src\java\org\apache\nutch\segment\ContentAsTextInputFormat.java` as per your needs.